# Stuck with a loop. After it fulfilled its function it keeps on going

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The first code is there to see if the number 20 is already in the spaces B28 till B47. If that is the case, I want it to move on to the next step. If the number 20 is not there, then i would like it to add the number to line B47 and then end after completing that. I'm haing problems trying to get it to stop after it added the number 20. Instead of ending, it continues down the column and adds een more 20s due to it not finidng any. What I have been trying to create is a loop which checks all the cells first, and if it does not find 20 it adds it once, instead of adding it 20 times.

The second code I hae after this is there to try to delete all empty rows in B28 till B47. However, it does not do that and skips this loop entirely moving to Blargh3 instead. I have tried creating loops for this, but Excel has always been giving me an error with it. I have tried researching as to how I could fix it after i have tried myself. I was not able to find anything which helped me.

As I am quite new to VBA, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B28:B48")
    If Cell.Value > 19 Then
        GoTo Blargh2
            Else:
            Range("B" & 47, "BM" & 47).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("B" & 47) = 20
            Dim a As Long
            For a = 3 To 65
            Cells(47, a) = 3
        Next
    End If
Next


Blargh2:
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B28:B47")
    If Cell.Value = 0 Then
        Row.Delete X1DeleteShiftUp
        Else:
        GoTo Blargh3
    End If
Next

Blargh3:
Dim i As Long
For i = 47 To 29 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i) - Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, 0) > 1 Then
        Range("B" & i, "BM" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("B" & i) = Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0) - 1
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 3 To 65
            Cells(i, c) = 3
        Next
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: it sounds like 2 separate questions, none of which demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Also, its very unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. Consider editing your question to better explain the logic in both loops. Do it like step by step

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? i.e. data/table before and after your macro?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a number to the bottom of a list before a loop starts finding missing numbers in the list and starts adding them in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237125/how-to-add-a-number-to-the-bottom-of-a-list-before-a-loop-starts-finding-missing)

Comment: this is still very unclear what you are trying to do. Take @Peters advice and show us a screenshot(s) of the process.

Comment: I have tried, but it says that I nned to have more reputation in order to post the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on your Immediate Window -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> or in the menu bar click *`View`* => *`Immediate Window`*

This would be the first part based on your logic

```
Sub FirstPart()

    Dim is20There As Range

    With Range("B28:B47")
        Set is20There = .Find(What:="20", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    End With

    If is20There Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "20 is not there, executing your code now"
        Range("B" & 47, "BM" & 47).Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("B" & 47) = 20
        Dim a As Long
        For a = 3 To 65
            Cells(47, a) = 3
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "exiting because 20 is there"
    End If
End Sub
```

What happens here in the first loop is

using the `.Find` function in range `B28:B47` to find the value of 20. If the value is there then the `Else` part of the loop will execute which simply does nothing but prints a message to the Immediate Window that 20 has been found.

this is when the 20 is not there
[image]

If 20 is not found (`If is20There is Nothing` evaluates to `True`) then you can execute your code which I guess adds a row at B47 (shifting the last row down ) and fills the cells with number 3 all the way down to 65th column except the B column which you seem to assign number 20 to.

So if 20 is not there the code literally does nothing.

this is when 20 is there (*nothing happens*)

[image]

---

The second part loops through B28:B47 backwards ( starting form the end to beginning ) and deletes the entire rows if any of them are empty ( column B only )

this is before

[image]

then run the code

```
Sub SecondPart()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    For i = 47 To 28 Step -1
        Set cell = Range("B" & i)
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

and this is after

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you very much. the code works now thanks to you. Im really gratefull that you helped me. I started VBA just a couple of days ago. Thanks so much for helping. I'm ever so slowly beginning to understand how to code with VBA.

Comment: @energygod5 no problem. For the future try to be more explicit about what you are trying to do. learn to step through your own code and debug it, read about breakpoints and local window. stepping through will show you the execution flow etc. Also, when asking questions in the future try to put more effort into being clearer and better explaining what the actual problem is :) Good luck

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :)